# Laravel - where like returns all records

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, collections, eloquent

I am trying to do a search page and when my search form is empty i am getting all records from table instead of empty/null.

My route:

```
Route::get('/search', 'SearchController@index');
```

In controller I am doing it like this:

```
$query = $input["query"]; //getting query from form
$results = Table::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')->get();
```

Output:

> Collection {#1505 ▼
>
> #items: array:5 [▶] (which is all records in table)
>
> }

I am trying to get some empty collection or `null`.

> Collection {#1505 ▼
>
> #items: []
>
> }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the query is set:

```
$results = collect();

if ($query = $request->get('query')) // you could also $request->has('query')
{
    $results = Table::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->get();
}

return $results;
```

Comment: Be aware that these are different types of collections. The collection returned by `collect()` has less functionality and may break if called with some Eloquent specific code.